# How to set defaults to route path placeholder with two or more placeholders that are not in last position?

Tags: symfony

I want my controller to catch route without one or more parameters. I'm trying to set defaults to those.

```
/**
 * @Route("/calc/{credit}/{claim}/{decreasedCapital}",
 *     defaults={
 *     "credit": "null",
 *     "claim": "null",
 *     "decreasedCapital": "null",
 *     },
 *     name="commission_calc")
 */
public function calculatorAction($credit = null, $claim = null, $decreasedCapital = null)
{
```

But with route like this:

`.../calc/0//14` 
`.../calc///33`

... controller does not catch it.

I'm expecting for routes:

`.../calc/40//14` credit==40, claim==null, decreasedCapital==14

`.../calc///33` credit==null, claim==null, decreasedCapital==33

`.../calc///` credit==null, claim==null, decreasedCapital==null (this is stupid)

`.../calc/20//` credit==20, claim==null, decreasedCapital==null (and this)

Comment: I think you shuold change the method to POST, so you do not get complicated. Or try this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7316, change the strict_requirements parameter in config.yml

Comment: I quite don't get what wrong here why would you want thos kind or URL `/calc/0//14` and  `/calc///33` to work ? They don't make much sense

Comment: @GregoireDucharme because I want to return error with explanation that one of params are empty not just "no rout found"

Comment: `/calc/0//14` is pretty much the same as `/////calc/0///////14` or `/calc/0/14` you cant have parameter `{decreasedCapital}` without the previous one, is that what you're trying to do or in this case `/calc///33` 33 is `credit` ?

Comment: I want slashes to divide parameters. If space between slashes is empty I want default value for that parameter. To answer your question: for `/calc///33` 33 is `decreasedCapital`